# Can I get excel to refresh ~500 queries?

Tags: excel, refresh

I have set up a workbook which contains ~500 individual queries (one for each sheet  in the workbook where I am trying to collect daily information from the web.)  I can refresh each query individually without issues, but that clearly take a lot of manual operations.  When I attempt to refresh all, the workbook freezes for about an hour, then when I get control back I get a message that most of the queries timed out.

Is there a way to have excel refresh all of these queries?

I used the following code in VBA to create the queries.

```
Sub StatsFromWeb()

Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim Name As String
Dim ESPNID As String

n = Sheets("1-Player Roster").Range("A1", Sheets("1-Player Roster").Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
For i = 1 To n
    DoEvents
    Name = Sheets("1-Player Roster").Cells(i, 1).Value
    ESPNID = Sheets("1-Player Roster").Cells(i, 2).Value
    Sheets(Name).Activate
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://www.espn.com/nba/player/gamelog/_/id/" & ESPNID & "/", Destination:=Range("$AA$1"))
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = False
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = False
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = True
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your excel?

Comment: Why do you have 500 different queries? Wouldn't it be possible to write just ONE query for all the data and use pivot tables with filters for the 500 different report scenarios?

Comment: Teylyn, that would be great.  Is there a way to have one query pull data from multiple web addresses?  I'm not sure how I can consolidate.